# XSLT code for traversing node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have requirement to print the first child node of two different parent nodes. I have two nodes in XML as below. I have added only a part of my xml code:

```
<UserValue title="project_variants" value="">
    <UserList id="id19" type="list">
    <Item value="LTD3,A"></Item>
    <Item value="LTD4,B"></Item>
    <Item value="PRODUCTION,B"></Item></UserList>
</UserValue>  
<UserValue title="ver2_rc_qty_pt" value="">
<UserList id="id11" type="list">
<Item value="1 EACH"></Item>
<Item value="2 EACH"></Item>
<Item value="3 EACH"></Item></UserList></UserValue>
```

Expected output is as below.

- Table First row should contain LD3    A   1 EACH
- Table Second row should contain LD4   B   2 EACH
- Table Third row should contain Production B   3 EACH

  ```
  LTD3       A 1 EACH
  LTD4       B 2 EACH
  PRODUCTION B 3 EACH
  ```

Comment: Please show your XSLT and explain what doesn't work about it, and/or what you don't understand.  Also, the XML is not well formed, it should have a single root element and your sample has two.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Instead, edit your original question and clarify the things you have been asked to.clarify.

Comment: sure, actually i m new to this site , next time will take care